# Javascript: document.body.appendchild has a null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, typeerror

I am loading a .js file I wrote. Within that .js file I am creating a Iframe like this

```
var frmSource = "http://MYLINK.com/mypage.php?" + encodeURI(URLBuilder);
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", frmSource);a
ifrm.style.width = 0+"px";
ifrm.style.height = 0+"px";
ifrm.setAttribute("frameBorder", "0");
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

URLBuilder contains the GET variables to the next page
The issue occurs at document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

and my error is 
javascript typeerror: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.appendchild')

I suspect the issue is it is trying to append the iframe to the body but the body has not properly loaded. I am currently only getting this issue in safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this to configure my IFrame creation and it is working fine

```
 var urlWithParam = url + encodeURI(URLBuilder)
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = urlWithParam;
        iframe.id = "iframe_" + done;
        iframe.style.position = "relative";
        iframe.style.height = "100%";
        iframe.style.width = "100%";
        iframe.style.top = "0";
        iframe.style.left = "0";
        iframe.style.right = "0";
        iframe.style.bottom = "0";
        iframe.style.frameBorder = "0";
        iframe.style.borderStyle = "none";
        iframe.style.display = "none;";


        //if you want to do something after the Iframe load
        iframe.onload = function(event) {

        };
```

Comment: I am marking this one correct. It is the closest to what I implemented. 

I ended up editing the code I provided above to this and seems to work every time


        window.onload = function() {
        *CODE here*
        };

Answer (score 2):

If your script is in the head, then the body is not defined (null). Put the script in the footer.

Comment: It is currently firing from inside of the body of page I am displaying to users.

Answer (score 1):

Moved the script below the body. And it worked like a charm.